# Want NIntegrate to catch error message

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

Really stuck with this.

When I use `NIntegrate`, it sometimes prints a message like

> NIntegrate::ncvb: "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 18 recursive bisections in y near {x,y} = {-0.974847,-0.999994}. NIntegrate obtained 1.6208370249645834`*^-13 and 4.441318688929174`*^-16 for the integral and error estimates."

What I want to do is to return 0 when such a message is produced. I tried wrapping in `Check`, e.g. `Check[NIntegrate[...], 0]`, but that doesn't stop the integration and the program just hangs. Also, it would be perfect if I could somehow extract the last obtained value from the message (1.6208370249645834`*^-13)

**The problem**

```
F11[x_, y_] := -((16 (3 x^4 + 6 x^2 y^2 - 5 y^4))/(9 (x^2 + y^2)^3));
F12[x_,y_] := -((32 x (x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4))/(3 (x^2 + y^2)^4));
F21[x_, y_] := (32 x (x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4))/(3 (x^2 + y^2)^4);
F22[x_, y_] := 
  (16 (33 x^6 - 180 x^5 y - 505 x^4 y^2 + 600 x^3 y^3 + 180 x y^5 - 
     515 x^2 y^4 - 35 y^6))/(3 (x^2 + y^2)^5);

K[x_, y_, i_, j_] := 
  Which[
    i == 1 && j==1, F11[x,y],
    i==1 && j==2, F12[x,y], 
    i==2 && j==1, F21[x,y], 
    i==2 && j==2, F22[x,y], 
    True, -12]; 

A[a_, i_, j_,n_,k_] := 
  NIntegrate[
    Sqrt[1 - x^2]*Sqrt[1 - y^2]*JacobiP[n, 1/2, 1/2, x]*JacobiP[k, 1/2, 1/2, y]*
      K[-2*a, x - y, i, j], 
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 3, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
```

I get the error message when evaluating `A[0.01, 1, 2, 1, 3]`.

Comment: The methods mentioned in question [1512](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated) should help somewhat towards aborting the computation. As for the rest of your question, could you post a code snippet to get some context for your problem?

Comment: @MarcoB thanks, I'll take a look. Also posted the snippet.

Comment: Try this : `Quiet[Check[ NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10000}, Method -> { Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}] ,  "invalid"] ]` .   Its pretty much what you say you tried though..

Comment: To the second part, see `$MessagePrePrint` for extracting the numbers.. they are often garbage though so I'm not sure thats a worthwhile thing to do.

Comment: @george2079 thanks for the comment. I tried the Quiet[Check combination, didn't work. What I did in the end, I removed Method -> "LocalAdaptive". It still prints a bunch of errors, but at least returns a value and doesn't hang.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/how-to-catch-complete-error-message-information

Comment: Also [avoid initial capital letters](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395) -- no really, you should [avoid initial capital letters](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=capital+letters).  Also `K` is used the by system (see `?K`).

Comment: For `A[0.01, 1, 2, 1, 3]`, I'm getting `15.2704` with no error messages.  (V10.1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the hint about capital letters. That's weird, mine was clearly printing an error, but it definitely wasn't 10.

Comment: If it is still giving errors, add the version information to the question.  The numerics algorithms tend to get updated with every release.

Comment: @MichaelE2 sure, I will double check it when I get to the computer with Mathematica

Answer (score 2):

This was not closed as being unreproducible, so I've decided to answer it, since I think this method may be useful to some.  I can adapt something I wrote for other purposes to address the outcome desired by the OP. I had occasion to write an extended version of `NIntegrateProfile` found in `` Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"] `` (see, for example, the tutorial [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html)). 
I adapted the `` Internal`AddHandler `` solution of [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) to
[How to abort on any message generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated) to capture the error estimate of `NIntegrate`.  I think it might be of general interest, so I will include it as well as adapt it to the OP's situation; it may also be helpful in the OP's case, depending on what exactly is desired.
It only catches the error estimate when `NIntegrate::ncvb` is produced, so it is not a (complete) solution to [Obtaining an NIntegrate error estimate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75426/obtaining-nintegrate-error-estimate).

**Hooking the `NIntegrate::ncvb` message.**  As shown by Szabolcs', we can use `` Internal`AddHandler `` to capture the parameters passed to `Message`.  In the case of `NIntegrate::ncvb`, some of the arguments are wrapped in `HoldForm`.  I do not recall the numeric parameters (e.g., the integral estimate) ever not being numeric, so I released the hold.  The potential for an evaluation leak might be introduced by this.

```
ClearAll[sowMessageData];
sowMessageData[
  Hold[Message[NIntegrate::ncvb, recur_, rvar_, vars_, vars0_, integral_, error_], _]] := 
    Sow[{"ErrorEstimate" -> ReleaseHold@error, 
      "PossibleSingularity" -> Thread[Map[HoldPattern, vars, {2}] -> vars0 // ReleaseHold]}, 
     sowNIntegrateData];

ClearAll[nintegrateProfile];
SetAttributes[nintegrateProfile, HoldAll];
nintegrateProfile[NIntegrate[args__]] := 
 Module[{evaluations = 0},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   Internal`AddHandler["Message", sowMessageData],
   Flatten[{
     Reap[Thread[{"Timing", "IntegralEstimate"} -> 
        AbsoluteTiming@ NIntegrate[args, EvaluationMonitor :> evaluations++]]],
     "Evaluations" -> evaluations}],
   Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", sowMessageData]
   ]]

nintegrateProfile[NIntegrate[1/x, {x, -0.5, 1}]]
nintegrateProfile[NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 0.5, 1}]]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.00095325}. NIntegrate obtained -3.67657 and 5.363161650917478` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*
  {"Timing" -> 0.088606, "IntegralEstimate" -> -3.67657, 
   "ErrorEstimate" -> 5.36316, "PossibleSingularity" -> {HoldPattern[x] -> 0.00095325}, 
   "Evaluations" -> 209}

  {"Timing" -> 0.002897, "IntegralEstimate" -> 0.693147, "Evaluations" -> 11}
*)
```

**The OP's goals.**  The first goal mentioned by the OP is to return `0` in case of `NIntegrate::ncvb`.  That's straightforward:

```
ClearAll[returnZeroOnNonconvergence];
returnZeroOnNonconvergence[
  Hold[Message[NIntegrate::ncvb, recur_, rvar_, vars_, vars0_, integral_, error_], _]] :=
     Return[0, NIntegrate];

Internal`WithLocalSettings[
 Internal`AddHandler["Message", returnZeroOnNonconvergence],
 NIntegrate[1/x, {x, -0.5, 1}],
 Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", returnZeroOnNonconvergence]
 ]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.00095325}. NIntegrate obtained -3.67657 and 5.363161650917478` for the integral and error estimates. >>

```
(*  0  *)
```

I'm a little confused by the OP's request to be able to "extract the last obtained value," because that is the value returned by `NIntegrate`.  In any case, the value is the argument `integral` to `sowMessageData` and maybe returned in whatever way desired (e.g. `Return[{0, integral}, NIntegrate]`).  And my first example `nintegrateProfile` can be adapted to return all of the parameters, if desired.