# Why do I get number with Precision larger than error estimate?

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision, error-tracking

I'm trying to integrate a large function like this

```
func[ξ_] = 1/(1167598657575 π Sqrt[1 - ξ]) 4 Sqrt[2/143] ξ Sqrt[(1 - ξ)/(1 + ξ)] (1 + 72 (-2 + 2 ξ^2) + 1197 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^2 + 7980 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^3 + 209475/8 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^4 + 92169/2 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^5 + 706629/16 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^6 + 43263/2 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^7 + 1081575/256 (-2 + 2 ξ^2)^8) ((8957659658839916544 - 38598804293820612608 ξ^2 + 69110375109906923520 ξ^4 - 66520053962590126080 ξ^6 + 37182509594538147840 ξ^8 - 12158541247606161408 ξ^10 + 2222643299988013056 ξ^12 - 202385520787169280 ξ^14 + 7047164723274720 ξ^16 - 40061762318655 ξ^18) ((1 + ξ) EllipticE[(2 ξ)/(1 + ξ)] - EllipticK[(2 ξ)/(1 + ξ)]) + 8 ξ^2 (279926864338747392 - 1127483203586621440 ξ^2 + 1863097027060039680 ξ^4 - 1626763404855214080 ξ^6 + 805078969740165120 ξ^8 - 224757138041339904 ξ^10 + 33055899621212160 ξ^12 - 2165655547777920 ξ^14 + 40988123520795 ξ^16) EllipticK[(2 ξ)/(1 + ξ)]);
```

in the following modes (error estimate extraction is from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102469/5208)):

```
arb16 = NIntegrate[func[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
  IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#@"Error"]) &)]
arb200 = NIntegrate[func[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 200]
```

I get the numbers, and now try to get the precision of `arb16`. Here's what I have:

```
Row[{"arb16 precision: ", -Log10@Abs[arb200 - arb16],
  ", precision by error estimator: ", -Log10@Total@errors,
  "\nreturned precision ", Precision@arb16,
  ", accuracy ", Accuracy@arb16}]
```

> arb16 precision: 10.3694098, precision by error estimator: 8.9544353783245526
>
> returned precision 16., accuracy 17.7955803201903

So, the error estimate by `NIntegrate` appears correct, but `Precision` and `Accuracy` of the number are still way too optimistic. Why is it so? Is there a way to force the correct precision numbers to be given out by `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Try using `PrecisionGoal`.

Comment: @ilian this is the inverse of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 10):

Consider any numerical integration method $I^*(f,a,b)$ that approximates the exact integral $I$ of a function $f$ over an interval $[a,b]$. It will be implemented by a computation represented by, say, `I[f[x], {x, a, b}]`. Conceiving an `NIntegrate[]` command in this way breaks the error into two independent components. The first is the error of the method $I^* - I$, where $I^* = I^*(f,a,b)$ is assumed to be computed exactly; this error is often called the "truncation error." The second is the difference between $I^*$ and `I[f[x], {x, a, b}]`; this error is usually thought of as "rounding error."

The error estimator of an `NIntegrate[]` method endeavors to yield an ***upper bound*** on the truncation error.  The options [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html) and [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html) set the goal for this bound. The error estimate is often done by comparing the method with a less accurate method, e.g. in the [`"GaussKronrodRule"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) and the [`"ClenshawCurtisRule"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#486402291).  For a well-behaved function, using either of these rules, the error can be greatly overestimated, as noted in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119390/4999).

The option [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html), which controls the [`Precision[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) and [`Accuracy[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) of the result, is used to control rounding error.  (It also affects the default `PrecisionGoal`, which affects the bound on the truncation error discussed above and which [@ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) also notes in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126645/4999).)  `Precision@arb16` and `Accuracy@arb16` reflect this rounding error.  Normally this, too, is an upper bound.**  So `Precision[]` has little to do with the truncation error in approximating the integral.

The general approach in numerical analysis has tended to focus on bounding error.  *Mathematica's* error estimators and arbitrary-precision numerics follow this approach. I don't believe there is a way to get a better estimate of the error, without knowing the exact value of the integral or computing it to a higher precision. (One could perhaps use a rule with a good error estimator; the approach in the rule `chebRule` in the linked answer above does somewhat better on a function that is analytic on `{0, 1}` than `"GaussKronrodRule"`, but the OP's function has a singularity at `1`.)

---

**Technical note: The precision-tracking rules used to keep track of the precision of a computation are based on linear approximation of the error. They do not produce an upper bound in themselves but aim to be accurate.  However, *Mathematica* keeps extra guard bits in the internal representation of arbitrary-precision numbers, so that the actual internal number computed usually has a rounding error of much less magnitude than the `Precision[]` and `Accuracy[]`.

Comment: Great explanation, +1.

Answer (score 4):

[Too long to type as a comment, but here is why `PrecisionGoal` is relevant]

Any number has a precision, and `Precision[arb16]` reflects only the uncertainty in the value of `arb16` as a number. It is determined by both the precision of the input, and all the arithmetic operations subsequently done with it (see *rounding error* in [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s excellent [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126648/145)).

What it *isn't* necessarily related to is the error of the integration method, that is `Precision[arb16]` has nothing to do with how correct the obtained integral value is.

Since you only specified `WorkingPrecision` to be 16, but left the precision goal at the default setting (`Automatic`, which in this case is effectively half of the working precision), you should only expect the result to approximate the value of the integral up to (at least) 8 digits  of precision. Since `arb16` certainly satisfies this, `NIntegrate` has fulfilled its contract.

The way to tell `NIntegrate` you want a result with more correct digits is to specify `PrecisionGoal`, which, as documented, sets convergence criteria by putting an upper bound on the estimated integration error (aka *truncation error* in [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s answer). For an example,

```
arb16a = NIntegrate[func[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, PrecisionGoal -> 16]

(* -0.01601104510443394 *)
```

does indeed have (no less than) 16 correct digits.