# How to reap error estimate from NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

Sometimes `NIntegrate` issues a warning stating that the desired accuracy wasn't reached.

```
NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[100 x]], {x, 0, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

> NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 0 
>   recursive bisections in x near {x} = {4.9602...}.   NIntegrate obtained 0.4780... and 0.3486... for the integral and error estimates. >>

How do I reap this error estimate (of 0.3486... in this case) from `NIntegrate` even when this warning is not issued?

Comment: Or this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75426/obtaining-an-nintegrate-error-estimate

Comment: Using Anton's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663): `Reap[NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[100 x]], {x, 0, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 0, "IntegrationMonitor" :> Function[{iregs}, Sow[Flatten[Map[Thread[# -> Through[iregs[#]]] &, {"Integral", "Error"}]]]]]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, thanks; close as duplicate.