# Numerical and analytical result for integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Consider the following integrand

```
integrand = (Cos[q] Sin[q])/((Cos[q]^2-10^-10 (6-2 Sin[q])^2+I 10^-20) (Sin[q]-4));
```

I would like to integrate this over `0 < q < π/2`:

```
res = Integrate[integrand, {q, 0, π/2}];
```

The exact result is approximately equal to:

```
N[res, 30]
```

> [image]

Now, if I try to compute the same integral numerically, the result deviates and has a rather big [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102469/5517):

```
N[
  {
    NIntegrate[integrand, {q, 0, π/2}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
    AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
    Method -> "DoubleExponentialOscillatory", 
    IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)]
  , 
    Total@errors
  }
, 30] // Quiet
```

> [image]

I tried all available Methods, and various MinRecursion and MaxRecursion options. Nothing seems to improve the numerics. Is there a way to calculate this integral purely numerically to get agreement with exact integration at least for a couple first digits? (My actual integrals I need to calculate are similar but do not have such nice coefficients, so that exact routine never finishes calculation.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not choose a contour that avoids the pole?

```
NIntegrate[integrand,{q, 0, -I, -I+Pi/2,Pi/2}]
```

> -3.34504 + 0.523599 I

Comment: This is pure genius! I'd give +10 if I could.